# checking email using $.post jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

i have a problem with $.post in jQuery .. When i want to get data from a php file .. 
i have :

```
user_e = form.Email.value;
if(user_e === "" ) {
  $("#i2").css({
    "border" : "1px red solid"
  });

  $("#i2").keyup(function(){
    $(this).css({
      "border": "1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"
    });
  });
  return false;
} else {
  var email = user_e ;
  $.post("email_checker.php", {email : email} ,function(data){
    return data ;
  })
};
```

and in "email_checker.php" file .. i added this code :

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
  $email = $_POST['email'] ;
  if(!empty($email)){
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false ){
      echo '<script>alert("code is working")</script>';
    }
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work :'( .. so who can help me please !

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: If you want to execute `PHP` file that has `Javascript` code in it and expect the alert to be displayed, you're in the wrong.

Comment: php echoing alert on php page and you are using ajax to get that data.

Comment: i edited the code ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your PHP code as below:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
  $email = $_POST['email'] ;
  if(!empty($email)){
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false ){
      echo 'code is working"';
    } else {
        echo "Email is not valid";
    }

  }
}
?>
```

and your AJAX call as:

```
$.post("email_checker.php", {email : email} ,function(data){
    alert(data);
    return false ;
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You have made mistake at passing arguments to $.post

It would be;

```
 `var email_value="abc@gmail.com";

  $.post("email_checker.php", function({email : email_value},status){
       alert("Status: " + status);
  })`
```

See example:
[jquery_ajax_post](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_post)

See reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Where is `status` defined?